# react testing with rtl, useselector value not getting as expected

Tags: reactjs, register-transfer-level, useselector

In react app implemented multitencay, and loading but not working as expected

test.only('should display only relevant search results when a user searches for a lesson by lesson name', async () => {
useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) =>
callback({
userSaving: mockUser,
lessonsLoad: true,
})
);

```
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // need fake timers because search has debounce / delay

  axios.get.mockImplementationOnce((mockUrl) => {
    switch (mockUrl) {
      case lessonsUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.Lessons);
      case aircraftFilterUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterAircraft);
      case statusUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterStatuses);
      case flightPhaseFilterUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterFlightPhase);
      default:
        return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'));
    }
  });

  renderLessonLibraryContainer();

  expect(screen.getByTestId('lessons-search-skeleton')).toBeInTheDocument();

  useSelector.mockClear();

  useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) =>
    callback({
      userSaving: mockUser,
      lessonsLoad: false,
    })
  );

  expect(await screen.findByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson1RowText })).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(await screen.findByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson2RowText })).toBeInTheDocument();

  //   expect(screen.queryByTestId('lessons-search-skeleton')).toBeNull();

  // Lesson Name search
  await searchTypeHelper('2');

  expect(screen.getByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson2RowText })).toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.queryByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson1RowText })).toBeNull();
});
```

content should be visible, after using 2nd useselector but not giving expected

test.only('should display only relevant search results when a user searches for a lesson by lesson name', async () => {
useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) =>
callback({
userSaving: mockUser,
lessonsLoad: true,
})
);

```
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // need fake timers because search has debounce / delay

  axios.get.mockImplementationOnce((mockUrl) => {
    switch (mockUrl) {
      case lessonsUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.Lessons);
      case aircraftFilterUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterAircraft);
      case statusUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterStatuses);
      case flightPhaseFilterUrl:
        return Promise.resolve(mockAPIResponseV2.GET.Success.FilterFlightPhase);
      default:
        return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'));
    }
  });

  renderLessonLibraryContainer();

  expect(screen.getByTestId('lessons-search-skeleton')).toBeInTheDocument();

  useSelector.mockClear();

  useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) =>
    callback({
      userSaving: mockUser,
      lessonsLoad: false,
    })
  );

  expect(await screen.findByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson1RowText })).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(await screen.findByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson2RowText })).toBeInTheDocument();

expect(screen.queryByTestId('lessons-search-skeleton')).toBeNull();

  // Lesson Name search
  await searchTypeHelper('2');

  expect(screen.getByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson2RowText })).toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.queryByRole(rtlRoles.ROW, { name: lesson1RowText })).toBeNull();
});
```